# Gmail shortcut for open spelling corrections hides window - any way to fix?

Tags: keyboard, google-chrome, gmail

The [gmail shortcuts list](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6594?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) says to "Open spelling suggestions" you press Command-M, but that minimizes the Google Chrome window for me. Any way to get a workable shortcut for this?

Comment: Did you test Ctrl/M or Cmd/Shift/M [sometimes they work as alternatives]

Comment: @Tetsujin I did test Ctrl/M before. Just tried Cmd/Shift/M and that is activating a Fantastical widget for me, with no preference to turn off. So not sure if that would otherwise do it for me in gmail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Chrome has an actual Minimise key command, you can change it to be something different

**Before**
[image]

System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts
Hit + then set the app to Google Chrome, menu item to Minimise & the key to something you don't use anywhere else

[image]

That should free up  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>M</kbd>  just for Chrome, yet it will still function correctly elsewhere.

**After**

[image]

Note it adds an  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>  version for Minimise All, which tends to be a common side effect of doing this type of replacement.

Comment: Thanks, that took away the minimize problem, but now Cmd-M does nothing. Unlike the gmail shortcuts page says, it doesn't bring up spelling corrections widget.

Comment: ahhh... that might be one to ask Gmail then. Sorry, it's not something i use.